# Cache external API requests in Vue/Nuxt app

Tags: vue.js, caching, request, nuxt.js

I consume external API in my Vue/Nuxt app. What I wanted is to somehow cache requests. Should it be done on Vue app or? Maybe to create mini Nodejs app that will act as middleware API and will cache external requests for my Vue app? Does anyone have some constructive suggestions, how to achieve this?

Comment: It depends on why you want to use caching. For example, if you would want to reduce the amount of data the client needs to fetch you should "cache" the data in the client side with something like local storage, Vuex store, service worker, etc. If your goal is to reduce the number of queries you make to the external api (because of cost per request, etc.) then yes, an intermediary service could be useful.

Comment: You might get better answers on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ or https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ though since this question seems a bit too broad for StackOverflow.